# AttributeError for imported class with Flask

Tags: python

I am importing a class `termIndex`. The class works fine on its own, but I am getting a "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'search' when I call the class's search function from within another function.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from TermIndex import termIndex

index = termIndex()
index.load(pickleFile) # No problem here
index.search(term) # No problem here

...

@app.route('/data')
def data():
    index.search(term) # This is where I get the Attribute Error
```

I've tried throwing in `global index` at the start of the data function but that didn't help.

EDIT: Like so, I get no error:

```
@app.route('/data')
def data():
    index = termIndex()
    index.load(pickleFile)
    index.search(term)
```

and like so, I get no error:

```
index = termIndex()
index.load(pickleFile)

def data():
    index.search(term)

data()
```

Which is why I've tagged flask.

Comment: Do you have `index = termIndex` (without `()`) anywhere in your code? In that case you'd reassign the `index` variable to the function reference instead.

Comment: This likely has nothing to with Flask, and is just an error in assuming what the type of `index` is.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message you describe, it's likely that you are defining an `index` function in the `...` part of your code that you've left out of the question. That makes it impossible for `data` to see the original `index` value, it sees the function instead.

Here's a simpler example of the same issue:

```
x = "foo bar"
x.split()          # this works here, since the name x refers to a string

def x(): pass      # this rebinds the name x to a function

x.split()          # raises an AttributeError since functions don't have a split method
```

To fix the problem, you just need to rename either the `index` function or rename the `index` variable you've shown us.